# Deploying dash app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, setuptools version error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, pip, plotly-dash

I've developed and tested a dash app. It works as expected. Next step is to deploy the app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using a preconfigured Docker container.

I am currently trying to set up a local docker environment for testing as described [here](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/deploying-dash-to-elastic-beanstalk)

Running the command (via PowerShell):

```
docker build -t dash-app -f Dockerfile.
```

successfully downloads the preconfigured image, then proceeds to install python modules as specified in requirements.txt, until it gets to the cryptography module, where it throws a runtime error saying it requires setuptools version 18.5 or newer.

[image]

My Dockerfile has this line in it:

```
FROM amazon/aws-eb-python:3.4.2-onbuild-3.5.1
```

I've tried adding a line to the dockerfile to force upgrade pip and setuptools within the container as suggested [here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/170) and [here](https://github.com/mozilla-services/syncserver/issues/143), but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried installing setuptools and cryptography in sequence i.e. `pip install setuptools; pip install cryptography` rather than `pip install -r reqs.txt` where reqs.txt contains a list of your packages.

Comment: @shiva, yes, i have. doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I can't help you with an answer.
But I'm facing the same problem, but with dash instead of cryptography:

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /var/app/build/dash